# Are the ring of primes to the power of integers isomorphic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I would like to know if the groups

$(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z},+)$
and   $((\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n},+)$

(where p is a prime number and n an integer) are isomorphic.

I already found that when p=2 and n=2, these groups are not isomorphic, but is it true for all p and n ? And how to prove it ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In $((\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n},+)$ every element $x$ satisfies $px=0$, which is not true in $(\mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z},+)$  In the second it takes adding  $p^n$ copies of $1$ to get to $0$

Comment: Then they aren't isomorphic for all n, p ?

Comment: That is correct.  It is probably generalizing what you found for $n=p=2$